# Need oracle query that merges two rows with user ids into one row with multiple user columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in a large table that looks like this:

| case_nbr | event_id | event_desc | User_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 1001 | Start Discussion |  |
| 201 | 1002 | Push Agent | U67800 |
| 201 | 1003 | Accept | U67800 |
| 201 | 1004 | Transfer | U67800 |
| 201 | 1005 | Push Agent | U67999 |
| 201 | 1006 | Accept | U67999 |
| 201 | 1007 | Transfer | U67999 |
| 201 | 1008 | Push Agent | U11800 |
| 201 | 1009 | Accept | U11800 |
| 201 | 1010 | Transfer | U11800 |
| 201 | 1011 | Complete | U11800 |

I need a query where it answers when an item was given to user and who it came from. I'd expect the output to look like this:

| case_nbr | TRANSFER_FROM | TRANSFER_TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201 |  | U67800 |
| 201 | U67800 | U67999 |
| 201 | U67999 | U11800 |

Can anyone tell me what the query would look like?
Thanks!

Comment: The logic is not clear how to tile those values with respect to `FROM` and `TO` columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY case_nbr
  ORDER     BY event_id
  MEASURES
    FIRST(user_id) AS transfer_from,
    NEXT(user_id)  AS transfer_to
  PATTERN (same_user+)
  DEFINE
    same_user AS FIRST(user_id) = user_id
              OR ( FIRST(user_id) IS NULL AND user_id IS NULL )
)
WHERE transfer_to IS NOT NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (case_nbr, event_id, event_desc, User_ID) AS
SELECT 201, 1001, 'Start Discussion', NULL     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1002, 'Push Agent',       'U67800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1003, 'Accept',           'U67800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1004, 'Transfer',         'U67800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1005, 'Push Agent',       'U67999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1006, 'Accept',           'U67999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1007, 'Transfer',         'U67999' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1008, 'Push Agent',       'U11800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1009, 'Accept',           'U11800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1010, 'Transfer',         'U11800' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 201, 1011, 'Complete',         'U11800' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CASE_NBR | TRANSFER_FROM | TRANSFER_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 201 | *null* | U67800 |
> | 201 | U67800 | U67999 |
> | 201 | U67999 | U11800 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b50eb99abce4f9353b9716642662b9b6)*